# How to include identifier column in aggregate result (R)

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data frame and would like to get the minimum value of the columns `A`, `B`, `C` for every group.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = seq(1,9,1),
                group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                A = runif(9, min=0, max=10),
                B = runif(9, min=-10, max=10),
                C = runif(9, min=0, max=100))

require(reshape2)
df_melt <- melt(data = df, id.vars = c("ID", "group"))


dat_min <- aggregate(x = df_melt[, 4], 
                     by = list(group = df_melt$group, variable = df_melt$variable), 
                     FUN = min, 
                     na.rm=TRUE)
```

I would like to have the column `ID` attached to the `dat_min` data frame, so that the resulting data frame is:

```
group   variable          x         ID
1        A          0.4934011       3
2        A          4.3482557       6
3        A          1.6423930       7
1        B          6.1969513       2
...     ...         ...             ...
```

Is this possible within `aggregate`? How could I include the ID column without actually using it in the grouping/aggregating process?

Comment: you should add a `set.seed` call at the start, so we can reproduce and understand your expected output

Comment: If ID is unique for a group / variable couple you can safely add it as a `by` parameter, if not it's not clear which ID you want to add to each row

Comment: I want to add the ID from column ID which belongs to the specific minimum value. The ID is unique for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the trick, it relies on filtering rather than aggregating to retain the minimum:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(var, val, A, B, C) %>%
  group_by(group, var) %>%
  arrange(group, val) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
```

If you're fairly confident that no value will be repeated, this might work:

```
df %>% 
  gather(var, val, A, B, C) %>%
  group_by(group, var) %>%
  summarize(min_val = min(val),
            id = max(ID * (val == min(val))))
```

Recreated to get multiple lines if there are ties:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ID = seq(1,9,1),
                 group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 A = sample(1:5, 9, replace = TRUE),
                 B = sample(1:5, 9, replace = TRUE),
                 C = sample(1:5, 9, replace = TRUE))

df %>% 
  gather(var, val, A, B, C) %>%
  group_by(group, var) %>%
  filter(val == max(val))
```

Change `max(val)` to `min(val)` if you want all rows with min values.

Comment: thank you very much. It works. How would you generate the maximum if you have repeated values?

Comment: Would you only want one value? Or all line numbers that had that value?

Comment: all line numbers with that value.

Comment: added a bit at the end